# Split string by a character(like ".","-" etc) and create directories in SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a string like `"abc.def.ghi.Hello"`
I want to write a shell script that creates folders structure like `abc/def/ghi/` and stores Hello in a new variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Parameter expansion.

Save the string in a variable.

```
string=abc.def.ghi.Hello
```

Remove everything but the `Hello`

```
hello=${string##*.}
```

Remove the `.Hello`

```
directory=${string%.*}
```

Replace all the dot `.` with a `/`

```
directory=${string//./\/}
```

Create the directories.

```
mkdir -p "$directory"
```

Print the variable which has `Hello`

```
echo "$hello"
```